# Send contact details to database using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a page that allows users to select contact names and details from their mobile device, what I am trying to do is then add those details to a mysql database using ajax.

Original code to get contact details from device.

```
 function select_a_contact()
    {
        intel.xdk.contacts.chooseContact();
    }

    document.addEventListener('intel.xdk.contacts.choose', function(evt){
        if (evt.success == true)
        {
            var contactID = evt.contactid;

            //this function retrieves information of a contact based on its id.
            var contactInfo = intel.xdk.contacts.getContactData(contactID);

            var firstName = contactInfo.first;
            var lastName = contactInfo.last;
            var phoneNumbers = contactInfo.phones;
            var emails = contactInfo.emails;
            var address = contactInfo.addresses;

            alert(firstName + lastName);
        }
        else if (evt.cancelled == true)
        {
            alert("Choose Contact Cancelled");
        }
    });
```

Here is my modified code where I have added some code to send the contact details to a php page. when I select a contact I don't get get any errors, but the Alert doesn't trigger so i am assuming that my code isn't working.  If i use the ajax code in a form environment it works perfectly, i have tried writing this several different ways but the ajax code doesn't seem to trigger.

```
 function select_a_contact()
    {
        intel.xdk.contacts.chooseContact();
    }

    document.addEventListener('intel.xdk.contacts.choose', function(evt){
        if (evt.success == true)
        {
            var contactID = evt.contactid;

            //this function retrieves information of a contact based on its id.
            var contactInfo = intel.xdk.contacts.getContactData(contactID);

            var firstName = contactInfo.first;
            var lastName = contactInfo.last;
            var phoneNumbers = contactInfo.phones;
            var emails = contactInfo.emails;
            var address = contactInfo.addresses;

            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://www.domian.co.uk/app/build.php",
            data: {
            var firstName = contactInfo.first;
            var lastName = contactInfo.last;
            var phoneNumbers = contactInfo.phones;
            var emails = contactInfo.emails;
            var address = contactInfo.addresses;
            },
            success: function(){
             alert(firstName);
            }
            });

            alert(firstName + lastName);
        }
        else if (evt.cancelled == true)
        {
            alert("Choose Contact Cancelled");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data portion is wrong. Try this instead:

```
data: {
    firstName: firstName,
    lastName: lastName,
    phoneNumbers: phoneNumbers,
    emails: emails,
    address: address
},
```

... or ...

```
data: {
    firstName: contactInfo.first,
    lastName: contactInfo.last,
    phoneNumbers: contactInfo.phones,
    emails: contactInfo.emails,
    address: contactInfo.addresses
},
```

Using the second you can get rid of all the new variable declarations, clean your code up a bit. You technically don't need them.

Comment: Thank you, i tried that, but again it doesn't trigger the alert or pass the information.

Comment: You'll need to include the code for build.php then. The problem likely lies there.